# why won't my program back up my file?

Tags: c++, backup

I'm working on a C++ project where I need to backup a data file after creating it within the same program. I have already created the data file and have successfully written text to it, however, when I've tried to backup the same file using the function I've written, it won't work.

Here is some context followed by the function:

The filename I created is named contactList.ext (.ext so it's created in the current directory). When prompted for the filename in this program I type in contactList and it opens successfully, however, the only problem I'm having is that it won't backup the file. I'm trying to back it up this way: newFileName = (fileName + ".bak");

I don't know what other way there is to backup a file using c++. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
void backupDataFile() {
    string fileName;
    string newFileName;
    string line;
    int contactListSize = 10, i = 0;
    string contacts[contactListSize];
    char userResponse;
    fstream inFile, outFile;

    cout << "\nEnter the name of the file you want to backup: ";
    cin >> fileName;

    inFile.open(fileName.c_str()); //attempts to open file

    //file fails to open
    if (inFile.fail()) {
        cout << "\nThe file " << fileName << " was not opened successfully."
             << "\n Please check that the file currently exists.\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    //read and display contents of file & assign each line to an array
    cout << "\nThe following is the contents of " << fileName << ":\n\n";

    while(getline(inFile, line)) {
        cout << line << endl;
        contacts[i] = line; //assigns each line to an array position
        i++;
    }
    inFile.close(); //closes existing file allowing the opening of a new file

    //verify user wishes to backup file
    cout << "\nWould you like to backup this file? <y/n>: ";
    cin >> userResponse;

    if (userResponse == 'y') {
        newFileName = (fileName + ".bak"); //assigns name of backup file

        outFile.open(newFileName.c_str()); //attempts to open backup file

        //file fails to create
        if (outFile.fail()) {
            cout << "\nThe file " << fileName << " did not backup successfully.";
            exit(1);
        }
        ///fix hereafter
        else { //writes contents from contactList.ext to contactList.bak
            while (i < 10) {
            cout << contacts[i] << endl; //writes each contact into new file
            i++;
            }
            //for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
              //  outFile << contacts[j] << endl;
        }
        outFile.close(); //closes file

        cout << "\nThe file " << fileName << " has been backed-up successfully."
             << "\nThe backup file is named " << newFileName;
    }//end outer-if
    else
        cout << "\nYou will be directed back to the Main Menu.";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies within these two sections.

```
 while (i < 10) {
            cout << contacts[i] << endl; //writes each contact into new file
            i++;
            }
            //for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
          //  outFile << contacts[j] << endl;
```

That for loop should not be commented out, you're only writing to the console (with cout), when you need to be writing to the outfile.

You also need to specify ios::out when calling outFile.out().

```
outFile.open(newFileName.c_str(),ios::out)
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing that to my attention! I didn't even see that. However, although that was a problem it wasn't the problem I was having. When the program runs, it doesn't ever get to that point... when asked y/n to backup the file it outputs "the file did not backup successfully." I still don't understand why this is?

Comment: You also need to specify ios::out, please see my above amendment.

Comment: Oh my gosh thank you so much!! It worked!!! Could you briefly explain to me what the ios::out does when I attempt to open the new file? Is it to specify which fstream is being used?

Comment: nevermind I found it in my textbook, it's to open the text file in output mode. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the other poster, you aren't actually running the code that outputs to the file

```
//outFile << contacts[j] << endl;
```

However another problem I see is that you output in a loop so long as i is less than 10. This is fine, but you didn't set i back to 0 after counting the number of lines when reading the file! That means that your

```
while(i < 10) {
```

loop never runs :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I changed i to j and set j = 0. However, the program doesn't ever get to that point... when asked y/n to backup the file it outputs "the file did not backup successfully." I still don't understand why this is?